# Generar distintos push en github con cuentas distintas

Tags: github

Estoy intentando resolver un problema de git pero no he encontrado información relevante sobre mi problema.
Resulta que en el trabajo hay veces que tengo ciertas ventanas o tiempos muertos por los que intento aprovecharlos estudiando o haciendo algun cursito. El problema radica en que en este computador tengo asociado en mi IDE(vs code) la cuenta github de la empresa por lo que si hago un push a mi repositorio personal toma el commit como si fuese de la cuenta de la empresa y eso NO quiero que sea así. Quiero que el push lo tome como mi cuenta personal

Tengo generada mis 2 sshkey ya, la de la empresa y la mia personal. Esto me ha servido solamente para hacer los clonados y así no me salte el problema de permisos o que no esta publico mi repositorio pero mi pregunta es esa.

Como puedo hacer para tener mas de una cuenta asociada en visual studio code para que cuando quiera hacer un PUSH lo tome con la cuenta que yo decida?

Gracias!

---

Respondiendo a @Alfabravo

La verdad no me funciona. Cuando termine de hacer las pruebass y que todo este OK edito el posteo para que sea útil para los demas de la comunidad.

Mira, tengo 2 archivos, está el config y el gitconfig

En el config se configura el archivo para poder clonar con distintas cuentas, entonces. Si quiero clonar con mi personal estos serían los pasos a seguir:
1.- En la carpeta .ssh donde se genera las sshkey crear un archivo config donde aquí indicare los distintos usuarios que tendré

```
#Cuenta Personal
Host nombreCuentaPersonal
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lagomarsinoh
```

Entonces...si quiero hacer un clone con mi cuenta personal tendría que ser asi:
ej:

```
https://nombreCuentaPersonal/usuarioGITHUB/nombreRepositorio
```

Eso funciona BIEN, ahora el problema radica en que cuando hago un push a ese repositorio clonado, lo está haciendo con mi cuenta del trabajo y no con mi cuenta personal.
El archivo .gitConfig está así:

```
 [user]
    name = Usuario Personal.
    email = usuarioPersonal@gmail.com
    
[user]
    name = Usuario LABORAL
    email = UsuarioLaboral@gmail.com
```

Dejando así el archivo al momento de hacer un push me toma el laboral mas no el personal, entiendo que me falta la última linea que me diste pero no entiendo como funciona.

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/proyectos_personales/"]
    path = ~/personal/.gitconfig
```

La forma que encontré de solucionar esto es que en el repositorio que este trabajando tengo que hacer un

```
get config --local user.name
get config --local user.email
```

y de esta manera funciona, pero no es lo correcto! :(

Me ayudas a solucionarlo, porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo esta [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860139/236345), el camino va por definir en el archivo `.gitconfig` el usuario (el email) que debe usarse en cada caso.

Si ya tienes las dos llaves (como indicas), sólo necesitas cambiar el archivo más o menos así

```
[user]
    name = Pepito Perez
    email = emailtrabajo@prueba.com

[includeIf "gitdir:~/proyectos_personales/"]
    path = ~/personal/.gitconfig
```

y en ese archivo `HOME/personal/.gitconfig`, pondrías algo como

```
[user]
    email = pepito.perez@personal.com
```

para que los repos clonados a ese directorio se manejen con ese email (y por lo tanto, con la llave correspondiente).

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responderme. Finalmente lo logre simplemente creando un config LOCAL en cada repositorio en el cual trabaje con mi cuenta personal.

ahora respecto a esta solución no logro entenderla.

el apartado donde pusiste [user] es lo que toma por defecto, es decir el trabajo

y abajo habria que poner otras lineas que digan [includeIf "direccion al repositorio Personal"] y el path al mismo archivo donde se esta trabajando? No entiendo

Comment: @Programmer89 tal cual. el path, incluso, funciona para una carpeta donde clones todos los repos personales, por ejemplo. Igual, pon tu propia respuesta, ya que te funcionó, indicando cómo ubicaste y configuraste el config local. Puedes marcarla como aceptada en un rato para que otros sepan que tu pregunta tiene esa solución :)

Comment: edite la publicación, me ayudas por favor